# Deploying DirectX/MFC app with Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2010, deployment, mfc, directx-11

I am able to run my app through the VS2010 environment. But cannot make it working as a stand-alone exe (to run it just by double click on exe). I don't know what files are required.

In VS in Additional Dependencies I have:

```
d3d11.lib
d3dcompiler.lib
d3dx11d.lib
d3dx9d.lib
dxerr.lib
dxguid.lib
winmm.lib
comctl32.lib
```

I tried to copy these files to the same directory where my exe is:

```
d3d11.dll
d3dcompier_43.dll
d3dx9d_43.dll
d3dx11d_43.dll
```

I also tried to find some dependencies, but the dependency walker crashes with some errors. So I used dependency scanner in InstallShield 2010, it said:

```
d3dx11d_43.dll
Microsoft (R) C Runtime Library
Microsoft OLE 2.40 for Windows NT(TM) and Window 95(TM) Operating Systems
VC User gdiPlus RTL X86
```

What are the last three things? What else can I do?

// EDIT

The app has been created by using DirectX SDK June 2010, so I have installed the DX End User June http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109 .

However, the app is working throught the VS2010, but the stand-alone exe (on the same computer) doesn't work, so I think the DX End User wasn't even necessary if I had SDK (the Visual C++ Redist was installed too).

I also tried to create a setup via VS2010, it copied these files:

```
COMDLG32.dll
d3d11.dll
d3dx11d_43.dll
IMM32.dll
MSIMG32.dll
OLEACC.dll
oledlg.dll
```

but it still doesn't work (while clicking on the exe it always displays the: Program xyz has stopped working. Windows can find a solution to this problem online. Find/Close/Debug buttons.)

Maybe it is something with the MFC?

Comment: I haven't done any directx in years, but as I recall, you need to create an installer that includes the DirectX installer and it needs to check the client to see if a suitable DirectX install already exists. You can't just copy the directX DLLs to the client. You need the version you're using (or a later version) installed properly by the DirectX installer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of just copying those DLLs, you'll need to install the [DirectX End-User Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8109) (the correct version, matching your development environment) on the user's system, as well as the [Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5555).

Comment: @tobi You need to actually use the distributable installer - not just copy DLLs.  They do system wide updates.

Comment: I have written in the edited post that I have installed the DX and VC++ redistributables, but it still doesn't work.